# React - "The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script"while build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to run "npm run build", earlier versions of project everything was okey but then it starts to giving me errors.

```
    > react-scripts build
    
    Creating an optimized production build...
    Failed to compile.
    
    The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script
    
    
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the crmreactclean@0.1.0 build script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-06T15_30_41_501Z-debug.log
```

debug.log:

````
...

    10 silly lifecycle crmreactclean@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts build' ]
    11 silly lifecycle crmreactclean@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
    12 info lifecycle crmreactclean@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
    13 verbose stack Error: crmreactclean@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
    13 verbose stack Exit status 1
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:375:28)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
    13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
    13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
    14 verbose pkgid crmreactclean@0.1.0
    15 verbose cwd C:\Users\fatih\Desktop\temiz build\crmreactclean
    16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
    17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
    18 verbose node v14.17.3
    19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
    20 error code ELIFECYCLE
    21 error errno 1
    22 error crmreactclean@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
    22 error Exit status 1
    23 error Failed at the crmreactclean@0.1.0 build script.
    23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    24 verbose exit [ 1, true ] ...```
````

And package.json

````
```{
  "name": "crmreactclean",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "antd": "^4.20.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bson-objectid": "^2.0.3",
    "d3": "^7.4.4",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-pro-sidebar": "^0.7.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.12.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-slidedown": "^2.4.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24"
  }
}```
````

I have tried so far;

1. To find a dynamic import in whole folder (including node_modules) but there isn't any. It may caused because of a dependency maybe
2. To build it on another computer.
3. To have a clean project and move folders and dependencies one by one.

I believed that tailwind caused this, since it hasn't installed on my last commit yet but I am confused now.

Answer (score 1):

Can you run `npm start`? If you can, I suggest to modify the `browserslist` in your `package.json` file and try to build again:

```json
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      "defaults and supports es6-module"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

I met the same issue when I tried to import from a CDN link in my project. `npm run` works well `npm run build` throws the exception. It turns out that it's not the fault of Webpack (see this [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8895)); it's just as the exception states that the building target environment doesn't support `import()`. So if you don't mind losing some (maybe trivial) browser compatibility, you can try this.